# Migrating content to different environments in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am evaluating DNN as an alternative to WSS. In WSS, I can migrate content and structure to different environments relatively easily (from dev to live, that is).

I am wondering how easily that is in DNN. Does anyone have that experience? Thank you so much.

Comment: I have found this to be a major weak point in DNN. We accomplish this by syncing databases. However, i may be perceiving this as a weak point because I have not stumbled across a proper solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Enterprise edition](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Products/Enterprise-Edition.aspx) has [content staging](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Products/Enterprise-Edition/Content-Staging.aspx), but otherwise it's mostly database sync for initial setup, and working on the live site after initial setup (using workflow in HTML, modules with future start dates, and module permissions to keep draft changes from being public).